# How can I generate code out of text in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, block, static-methods, dsl

Is there a way I could turn something like this:

```
SomeModule.some_method do
  choos_one_from 1..10
  then_multiply_it_by 2
  then_multiply_it_by 5
  then_divide_it_by :picked_number
  then_subtract 7
  did_you_get 3
end
```

into this:

```
(1..10).all? do |number|
  ((number * 2 * 5) / number) - 7 == 3
end
```

?

I tried to define methods for every possible (choose_one_from, then_multiply_it_by...) that take an argument and do something with it but so when yield the block it produces the values but I don't really know how to combine them so I can get the 2nd piece of code.

**EDIT** : I have the feeling that I have to make something like **DSL**

Answer (score 5):

You would want something like:

```
module Mathisizer

  def when_i
    Mathisizer::Builder.new
  end

  class Builder
    attr_accessor :range, :choosen_number

    def new
      @operations = []
    end

    def choose_one_from(range)
      self.range = range

      # Randomly determine the number from the range
      # self.choosen_number = ...

      self
    end

    def then_multiply_it_by(n)
      @operations << MultiplicationOperation.new(n)
      self
    end

    def then_add(n)
      @operations << AdditionOperation.new(n)
      self
    end

    def did_you_get?(n)
      x = self.result

      x == n
    end

    def result
      x = choosen_number;

      @operations.each do |operation|
        x = operation.invoke(x)
      end

      x
    end
  end

  class BaseOperation
    def new(n)
      @number = n
    end

    def invoke(n)
      raise 'Base classes must implement invoke(n) -> number'
    end
  end

  class MultiplicationOperation < BaseOperation
    def invoke(x)
      return @number * x
    end
  end

  class AdditionOperation < BaseOperation
    def invoke(x)
      return @number + x
    end
  end

end
```

Where you can use it like:

```
Mathisizer.when_i
  .choose_one_from(1..10)
  .then_multiply_it_by(5)
  .did_you_get?(3)
```

Basically you'd create a "builder" object that provides a fluent API for creating mathematical operation objects.

Comment: But, what if I don't know the order of the 'then_multiply_it', 'then_devide_it_by' . How would I make the proper chaining in Mathesizer.new ?

Comment: @user2128702 the methods are returning self, so the order does not matter

Comment: @GregBurghardt So, 'self' returns the whole Mathesizer object?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I don't think that I get it. I have only one single multiplier property. I don't know how to assign it if I had few of them between other operations. As you know the different operations have different priority.

Comment: The `self` variable returns the instance of Mathisizer.  Also, I see what you mean about the order of operations, which is a tad important for Math. You could maintain an array of operations. Each operation would be it's own class, and each operation class would contain a generic interface. Let me do some more thinking on this.